# Fake HTML Tag (for AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs

Will I run into problems when I use a fake HTML tag like:

```
<any></any>
```

I need this for a ng-if inside headings. If I use `<span>` I have to define it's CSS. So far I haven't run into problems with the newest Chrome/Safari builds. But will this work on phones, older browsers, etc?

Comment: Try IE8. In general, using invalid html doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: I take it that you want to do this because you want to make use of the ng-if directive but you really don't want to introduce a container around the conditionally shown content.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah I could do <h1 ng-if...>xy var1</h1> <h1 ng-if...>xy var2</h1> but I have a lot of cases where I just need to add one letter for the plural.

Comment: Have you seen that AngularJS already has a directive to [pluralize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize)?

Comment: No haven't seen that but it looks awesome.